# Using fold to sum List of object attributes

Tags: scala, fold

In this code I'm attempting to double each value and then sum v :

```
case class s(v : Int)
  val l = List(s(2) , s(3))                      
  l.fold(0) ((_.v * 2) + (_.v * 2))
```

But I receive error :

```
  value v is not a member of Any
```

How can I perform an operation on each attribute of the object within the List?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other authors also noted, `fold` expects the accumulator of the supertype for your class. The class itself is also a supertype for itself, so we can write

```
case class s(v : Int)
val l = List(s(2) , s(3))                      
l.fold(s(0)){case (acc, elem) => s((acc.v * 2) + (elem.v * 2))}.v
```

but that indeed feels too heavy. in this case the simple:

```
l.map(_.v*2).sum
```

would do better.

Answer (score 2):

The first element in the fold is the starting element and you are calling `0.v`, also note the fold signature is `def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1`, that means that it returns a variable of a type which is a super type of the passed type parameter, use `foldLeft` instead which allows you to build a value which is a subtype:

```
l.foldLeft(0) ((acc, curr) => acc + (curr.v * 2))
```

I used `acc` and `curr` to better visualize what was happening inside the fold, this is the abbreviated form:

```
l.foldLeft(0) (_ + _.v * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want, since the accumulator of your `fold` is of type `Int`, not of type `s`. Doing `_.v * 2` for an `Int` does not make sense.

You can either do a `foldLeft` (or `foldRight`):

```
l.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.v * 2)
```

Or even easier, use `map` and `sum`:

```
l.map(_.v * 2).sum
```